# Direct sum operation and endomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, direct-sum

I'm a physics student and I'm struggling with some concepts of Representation Theory.

I'm currently trying to understand the basics of it and in particular the mathematics that lies behind the concept of Reducible representation.

Let $G$ be a group. Let $X_i$, $i=1,\dots,n$ be vector spaces on the same field $\mathbb{K}$. For each $i$, let $D_i$ be a representation of $G$ on $X_i$. I have to show that the mapping $\oplus_iD_i\colon G\to \mathrm{End}(\oplus_iX_i)$ defined by

\begin{equation}
(\oplus_iD_i)(g)=\oplus_iD_i(g), \qquad g\in G
\end{equation}
is a representation of $G$ in $\oplus_iX_i$.

To show that I need to recall that:

- If $A_i\in \mathrm{End}(X_i)$ are endomorphisms then $\oplus _iA_i\in \mathrm{End}(\oplus _iX_i)$ and $(\oplus_iA_i)(\oplus_jx_j)=\oplus_i(A_ix_i)$
- If $A_i\in \mathrm{End}(X_i)$ are invertible endomorphisms, then $\oplus_iA_i$ is invertible
- If $A_i, B_i\in \mathrm{End}(X_i)$ then $(\oplus_i A_i )(\oplus_j B_j)=\oplus_i (A_i B_i)$.

I can't understand where these propositions come from. "Where" am I? I'm looking at a sum of objects that belongs to different monoids. Is it possible to generalize to every algebraic structure? For example, can I say something like

If $A_i, B_i\in X_i$ then $\oplus_iA_i\in\oplus_i X_i$ and $(\oplus_i A_i )+(\oplus_j B_j)=\oplus_i (A_i+ B_i)$

where "+" is the sum operation belonging to each vector space and $\oplus$ can freely move through the different spaces?

And lastly, what makes me say that $\oplus _iA_i\in \mathrm{End}(\oplus _iX_i)$ instead of $\oplus _iA_i\in \oplus _i\mathrm{End}(X_i)$?

I need some insight on the issue. As I said I'm not a math student so maybe I'm asking for the obvious... but any help, even if just a tip on where to take a look, will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: $\oplus_i D_i$ is "just" a notation. In particular, using your notations, $\oplus_i A_i$ is not a sum (well it could be but let's not complicate things), it's an endomorphism defined by $\oplus_i A_i (x) = A_j(x)$ when $x\in X_j$, and completed by linearity. It's a very important theorem that to define an endomorphism, you only need to define it on factors of a direct sum, so that $\oplus_i A_i$ is thus well-defined. The other propositions are a consequence of this definition

Comment: @OP I think you are making this too complicated.  Carefully write down the details of the case where $n = 2$ and you'll see what's going on.

Comment: @Max Thank you for your answer. I wasn't aware of the existence of such a theorem. Basically I was searching for an explanation when it's just a definition (this is a physicist disease maybe eheh). Last question: does $(\oplus_i A_i)(\oplus_j B_j)=\oplus_i(A_i B_i)$ comes from the linearity of $A_i$ or from a "component-wise nature" of the direct sum operation? Thank you very much for your patience :))

Comment: @D_S Thanks for your answer! You're right, I'm making this too complicated :) I have no problems with $\oplus_i$, I already tried with $n=2$ but I had the same doubts. Maybe I was just overthinking it when I should just stick to the fact that "I want to define an endomorphisms and I want it to be precisely like THIS", because there is this X theorem stating that it's well defined (as Max said on the comment above)

Comment: To answer your question in the comments above, this equality just follows from the fact on $X_j$, $\oplus_i A_i$ coincides with $A_j$, and $\oplus_i B_i$ coincides with $B_i$, so $(\oplus_i A_i)(\oplus_k B_k)$ coincides with $A_j B_j$. Then by the theorem I mentioned, this implies $(\oplus_i A_i)(\oplus_k B_k) =\oplus_i A_iB_i$

Comment: Got it! Thanks :)